# ionic + variable with number produces always 'is not a valid number'

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my page I use variables from the controller of the page. For example:

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
  <span class="input-label">Projekt Id:</span>
  <input type="number" placeholder="0" value="{{cpc.projektid}}" disabled>
</label>
```

The controller does some calculation over a factory, and get's also some data from an SQLite database. If I check the type of my variables in the controller or in the factory, i get for Example:

```
console.log(typeof cpcVm.projektid); => number
console.log(angular.isNumber(cpcVm.projektid)); 0> true
```

So for me, this means, that the value of the variable is a number!?

But I get always the warning:

> The specified value "{{cpc.projektid}}" is not a valid number. The
>   value must match to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?"

For the `projektid` this is not a big issue, but I have more complicated calculations, and I need also set some filters, which work only if the number is a number. For example:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="0" value="{{cpc.luftmenge | number:2}}" disabled>
```

I tried already to give an additional `parseFloat()` in my controller and the factory, but there is no change. The controller and the factory say it's a number, but in the HTML it creates an error, and I can't use the filter.

Another strange thing: If I set the value of the variable in the factory or the controller manually (for example return 12;), then it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-value="cpc.projektid"` instead of `value` attribute.

Till the Angular is not loaded in the page, what browser will see in the `value` attribute is `{{cpc.projektid}}` and that is why it is complaining. `ng-value` make sure that `value` attribute is only get added after the expression compiles properly.

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.projektid = "2"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  Projekt Id:
  <input type="number" placeholder="0" ng-value="projektid" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This solved my problem. I don't understand why it worked when I gave a manual value. Maybe it was because in the calculations i use other variables? I changed my complete code to ng-value="" and removed the parseFloat() stuff. In my tests it looks like everything would work...

Comment: Glad this worked! Like I mentioned in the answer when you were using `value="{{}}", for a second or may be millisecond, browser seeing the `value` be `{{cpc.projektid}}` till the Angular is not initialized in the DOM. As the Angular comes into play, now the browser gets the actual value after the expression `{{cpc.projektid}}` evaluated. Same goes for `src` and `ng-src` attributes.